# javascript Convert object to array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to convert object to array object?

input:

```js
{
  AF: 'Afghanistan',
  AX: 'Åland Islands',
  AL: 'Albania',
  DZ: 'Algeria'
}
```

output:

```html
[
    {value: 'AF', label: 'Afghanistan'},
    {value: 'AX', label: 'Åland Islands'},
    {value: 'AL', label: 'Albania'},
    {value: 'DZ', label: 'Algeria'}
]
```

Comment: `Object.entries(input).map(([value, label])=>({value,label}))`

Answer (score 3):

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object. This method returns an array with the keys of the object as string entries.
Then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that array, and return the desired object in the mapping function, the result will be the desired array.

```js
let countries = {
  AF: 'Afghanistan',
  AX: 'Åland Islands',
  AL: 'Albania',
  DZ: 'Algeria'
}

let arr = Object.keys(countries).map(key => {
   return {key: key, value: countries[key]}
});
console.log(arr);
```